# R site extension missing in Azure Functions

Tags: r, azure-functions

I am trying to install R script site extension to a azure function by following a tutorial. It is not on the list. Is there a work around?

Edit:
[image]

Comment: What list are you talking about? What exactly are you trying? What tutorial are you following? What step are you on?

Comment: @MrFlick the azure functions site extension list. I am on the step where I am trying to install the R site extension.

Answer (score 2):

R does not need to be installed. You can install it locally and copy the folder to your Azure Function via ftp.

I ran R using [R.Net](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet) in C#.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ExecutionContext context, TraceWriter log)
    {
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, @"R-3.4.4\bin\x64"), System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, @"R-3.4.4"));
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
        string[] a = engine.Evaluate("'Hi there .NET, from the R engine'").AsCharacter().ToArray();
        engine.Dispose();

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, a[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what we've done and it works fine. Note that you can access the app service filesystem through Storage Explorer.

Comment: @TomWright yes this will work however, I gave up on the solution because I need it real time. The problem is if the function is inactive it needs to cold start which finds a server to host the function and it needs to copy all the dll files to the server before it runs the function. Copying R library takes to long for a real time solution. If you host the function on your app service then this would work but I feel like that defeats the purpose of functions.. I just used a web api app instead.